# Is “Comment vas-tu” formal or casual?

Tags: interrogative, registre, tutoiement

Is “Comment vas-tu?” formal or casual? I have also tried asking other websites and it did not make any sense.

Comment: I’m upvoting this question because I’m convinced (by OP’s asking specifically about the “formal or casual” distinction instead of the “familiar or polite” [aka T/V] one) that s/he was simply (&, imo, cleverly [read: mischievously?] by throwing in a T/V aspect as a red herring trap for the unwary) asking if ... “'La forme interrogative directe inverse'=formal or casual.” ... cf: Is “Comment va[-il] le chien de **votre** mari” of a more formal register than “Comment va[-il] le chien de **ton** mari,” or is it just more polite (in recognition of the level of familiarity between the parties)?

Answer (score 4):

> *Comment vas-tu ?*

is a formal way to ask "how are you?" to someone you *tutoie*.

The casual way is:

> *Comment tu vas ?*

or just

> *Ça va ?*

Answer (score 0):

When using 'tu' it's definitely casual.

'Vous' can be formal and/or plural.

Comment: Using *tu* or *vous* is not a question of being formal or casual.

Comment: But the form _vas-tu_ is considerably more formal than _tu vas_.